# assert fails after (succesfully) selecting a plane using selectbyId2

Tags: vba, solidworks

In the following snippet the first assertion succeeds and the second fails (bStat=False) even though the selection has actually succeeded (plane is selected)

What am I missing? 
Thanks for advice/explanation

```
bStat = swDocExt.SelectByID2(FirstSelection, "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, swSelectOptionDefault) 
Debug.Assert bStat  

bStat = swDocExt.SelectByID2(SecondSelection, "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, swSelectOptionDefault)
Debug.Assert bStat
```

Note:
FirstSelection = "Front Plane@2x6 Wall-1@Assem1"

SecondSelection = "Front Plane@Assem1"

Answer (score 0):

If make assumption that you performing this code as it written, then there is only one way to get "false" at second SelectByID2 is a typo.

Try to record a macro as you selecting this planes in the FM (if you select them in graphical area their ID probably will be left blank). After that, save your macro in a language you prefer and open it for editing and you will see through which ID you can access them.

And if you have code between those lines, then probably you've already selected this plane and you're trying select it second time and in this case selection returns false.